# How to get mAP@ any IoU threshold in Yolov8 model?

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

I am currently using Yolov8 object detection and I want to get the mAP at any threshold. How did I do it?

I normally use model.val() to evaluate the model, but its only give mAP50 and mAP50-95 of all classes and each class. I expect the function that can calibrate IoU threshold such as mAP90, mAP1.

this is function that I used.
[text](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/val/)

- please noted that the iou key in that function is threshold for NMS, not for calculate the mAP

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.